# React access attributes of a class component from its parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Imagine the following scenario:

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <input value="123" />
  }
}

function App() {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  return (
    <Input ref={inputRef} />
  );
}
```

I want to access the input tag's `value` attribute in my `App` component.
However, `inputRef.current.value` is undefined.

How can I access attributes of a class component in React?

Comment: What's the overall goal?  Would it make more sense for the `<Input>` element to expose an `onChange` callback as a prop, and consuming code can optionally supply a function for that prop to be invoked when the value changes?

Comment: Well, this example is oversimplified. What I'm really asking is how I can communicate the attributes of a class component to its parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just pass the ref as a prop and use it in the class component.

```
import React from "react";

class Input extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { inputRef } = this.props;
    return <input ref={inputRef} name="inputExample" defaultValue="123" />;
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null);

  const logValue = () => {
    console.log(inputRef.current ? inputRef.current.value : "No Input found");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input inputRef={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={logValue} type="button">
        Input current value
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check the sandbox in case you want to see a live example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-curran-f6bhbrs-f6bhbr?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward the ref using `forwardRef` and set the `ref` to the `input` element as below.

#### Class component

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <input ref={this.props.innerRef} />;
  }
}

const MyInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Input innerRef={ref} {...props} />
));

function App() {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  const checkValue = () => {
    console.log(inputRef.current && inputRef.current.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <MyInput ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={checkValue}>check value</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

#### Function component

```js
const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <input ref={ref} />;
});

function App() {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  const checkValue = () => {
    console.log(inputRef.current && inputRef.current.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Input ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={checkValue}>check value</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: But I need `Input` to be a class component. I want to access the attributes of a class component from its parent component.

Comment: @Mystical, updated the answer! Since your `Input` in a single file. change the `export default Input` to export default `React.forwardRef(...`